# PGSQL - extra data column

Tags: database, postgresql, csv

Screenshot of the error:

[image]

Error: Extra data after last expected column

I imported from Excel to CSV format.
All fields must match the fields in the database, but cannot import. What could be the problem?

```sql
copy analytics.import_property_objects from '/home/dayanov-sa/PGadmin/finish2.csv'
(FORMAT CSV, HEADER, DELIMITER ';')
```

```
ERROR: could not open file "/home/dayanov-sa/PGadmin/finish2.csv" for reading: No such file or directory
SQL-состояние: 58P01
```

Also tried to implement using SQL query, but it gives an error.

Comment: Are you aware that `COPY` reads files from the database server machine? User `psql`'s `\copy` command to import files from the client. The first error message means that the CSV file has more columns than your database table.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe ERROR:  syntax error at or near "\"
LINE 1: \COPY analytics.import_property_objects from '/home/dayanov-...

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe http://i.prntscr.com/Nemhc4KvQyyvTRcsM2GVbQ.png

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I manually checked the number of fields in the table and in the csv file. 92 in the file and in the table.

Comment: Well, PostgreSQL seems to disagree. You can run `\copy` only from `psql`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Sorry, I did not quite understand you. I meant that he does not accept the command `\copy`. I have PGadmin

Comment: Yes. Don't use pgAdmin then, use `psql`.